# Customize Slack Command parameters

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

I wanted to customize my custom Slash commands that can accommodate multiple parameters. For instance, in the example given at [slack api documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), there is a command named

```
    /weather 94070
```

This only has one parameter

```
   94070
```

I just wanted to know if I can pass multiple parameters there like

```
    /weather 94070 Dallas 06-26-2016
```

I didn't see anywhere in the documentation about this. Has anyone ever come across this situation before?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, everything after the slash command keyword is passed to you in the `text` key.

[image: Data Slack sends]
So, to refer to the example Slack provides, instead of `94070` it would say `94070 Dallas 06-26-2016`

[More information](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#triggering_a_command)